# Converting `for` loop that can't be vectorized to sparse matrix

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave, sparse-matrix

There are 2 boxes and a small gap that allows 1 particle per second from one box to enter the other box. Whether a particle will go from A to B, or B to A depends on the ratio Pa/Ptot (Pa: number of particles in box A, Ptot: total particles in both boxes).

To make it faster, [I need to get rid of the `for` loops](http://www.variousconsequences.com/2009/01/how-to-speed-up-octave.html), however I can't find a way to either vectorize them or turn them into a sparse matrix that represents my `for` loop:

> What about for loops you can't vectorize? The ones where the result at iteration n depends on what you calculated in iteration n-1, n-2, etc. You can define a sparse matrix that represents your for loop and then do a sparse matrix solve.

But I can't figure out how to define a sparse matrix out of this. The simulation boils down to calculating:

[image]

where

[image]

is the piece that gives me trouble when trying to express my problem as described [here](http://www.variousconsequences.com/2008/12/more-on-speeding-up-octave.html). (*Note*: the contents in the  parenthesis are a bool operation)

**Questions**:

- Can I vectorize the `for` loop?
- If not, how can I define a sparse matrix?
- (bonus question) Why is the execution time **x27** faster in Python (0.027s) than Octave (0.75s)?

<sub>**Note**: I implemented the simulation in both Python and Octave and will soon do it on Matlab, therefor the tags are correct.</sub>

---

**Octave code**

```
1; % starting with `function` causes errors

function arr = Px_simulation (Pa_init, Ptot, t_arr)
  t_size = size(t_arr);
  arr = zeros(t_size);   % fixed size array is better than arr = [] 
  rand_arr = rand(t_size);  % create all rand values at once
  _Pa = Pa_init;
  for _j=t_arr()
    if (rand_arr(_j) * Ptot > _Pa)
      _Pa += 1;
    else
      _Pa -= 1;
    endif
    arr(_j) = _Pa;
  endfor
endfunction


t = 1:10^5;

for _i=1:3
  Ptot = 100*10^_i;
  tic()
  Pa_simulation = Px_simulation(Ptot, Ptot, t);
  toc()
  subplot(2,2,_i);
  plot(t, Pa_simulation, "-2;simulation;")
  title(strcat("{P}_{a0}=", num2str(Ptot), ',P=', num2str(Ptot)))
endfor
```

---

**Python**

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit
import cpuinfo

from random import random

print('\nCPU: {}'.format(cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand']))


PARTICLES_COUNT_LST = [1000, 10000, 100000]
DURATION = 10**5

t_vals = numpy.linspace(0, DURATION, DURATION)


def simulation(na_initial, ntotal, tvals):
    shape = numpy.shape(tvals)
    arr = numpy.zeros(shape)
    na_current = na_initial

    for i in range(len(tvals)):
        if random() > (na_current/ntotal):
            na_current += 1
        else:
            na_current -= 1
        arr[i] = na_current
    return arr


plot_lst = []
for i in PARTICLES_COUNT_LST:
    start_t = timeit.default_timer()
    n_a_simulation = simulation(na_initial=i, ntotal=i, tvals=t_vals)
    execution_time = (timeit.default_timer() - start_t)
    print('Execution time: {:.6}'.format(execution_time))
    plot_lst.append(n_a_simulation)


for i in range(len(PARTICLES_COUNT_LST)):
    plt.subplot('22{}'.format(i))
    plt.plot(t_vals, plot_lst[i], 'r')

    plt.grid(linestyle='dotted')
    plt.xlabel("time [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Particles in box A")

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you add a small reproducible data set and your desired data set?

Comment: I think the sparse matrix suggestion in the Octave link is to make a linear equation, `M*x=f`, where `M` is a sparse matrix. Finite element and finite differences use this solve PDEs.  Sparse matrices are widely used to represent the stiffness matrix of such linear equations.

Comment: @MaxU (I m new to vectorization and sparse matrices, so that might sound silly... but) what data set do you refer to? Shouldn't I first turn it into an Ax=B like [here](http://www.variousconsequences.com/2008/10/is-octave-slow.html)? I can't figure out how to create matrix A, so I can't provide a data set.

Comment: @hpaulj Does that mean that unless I can create a linear equation out of the formula for `p_n`, I can't use sparse matrices for the given problem?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `cumsum()` in both `Octave` and `Numpy`:

Octave:

```
>> p = rand(1, 5);
>> r = rand(1, 5);
>> p
p =

   0.43804   0.37906   0.18445   0.88555   0.58913

>> r
r =

   0.70735   0.41619   0.37457   0.72841   0.27605

>> cumsum (2*(p<(r+0.03)) - 1)
ans =

   1   2   3   2   1

>> (2*(p<(r+0.03)) - 1)
ans =

   1   1   1  -1  -1
```

Also note that the following function will return values (`[-1, 1]`):

[image]